# Deprecated Functionality: explode(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($string) of type string is deprecated in

Tags: magento2.4.4, php8

When running Magento 2.4.4 with PHP 8.1, if I use a block object's `getTemplateFile` method AND the block had no template set, I end up with an error that looks like this

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Exception): Deprecated Functionality: explode(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /usr/local/var/www/virtual-hosts/agento-2-4-4.localhost/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/framework/View/FileSystem.php on line 174

Exception #0 (Exception): Deprecated Functionality: explode(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /usr/local/var/www/virtual-hosts/magento-2-4-4.localhost/project-community-edition/vendor/magento/framework/View/FileSystem.php on line 174
<pre>#1 explode() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/FileSystem.php:174]
#2 Magento\Framework\View\FileSystem::normalizePath() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/FileSystem.php:119]
#3 Magento\Framework\View\FileSystem->getTemplateFileName() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template/File/Resolver.php:60]
#4 Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Resolver->getTemplateFileName() called at [vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Template.php:214]
```

If I follow the stack trace to the code in question, I get down to here

```
    #File: vendor/magento/framework/View/FileSystem.php 
    public static function normalizePath($path)
    {
        $parts = explode('/', $path);
        $result = [];
```

where is appears Magento is not property guarding/defaulting for the new, more strict, PHP 8.1 expectations around `explode`.

Is there a safer method to call to get a block's template?  Or is `getTemplateFile` something we should just expect to throw now and wrap calls in a try/catch.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a reason to use `getTemplateFile` method to the block before check is template is set to block or doesn't

I've reviewed a logic of this part in Magento and looks like it's a design bug with missed check and related exception

You can pass Magento style template path which you are want to receive to `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template::getTemplateFile` or the method will try to use defined template.

Make sense to create bug report or improvement to Magento and specify this case. I think Magento should throw exception in `\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\File\Resolver::getTemplateFileName` when empty template passed.

> Is there a safer method to call to get a block's template? Or is getTemplateFile something we should just expect to throw now and wrap calls in a try/catch.

I think a best solution of this will be check is template set before run `getTemplateFileName` like:

```php
if ($block->getTemplate()) {
    // your logic with $block->getTemplateFileName();
} else {
    // block doesn't have defined template
}
```